# Standing Orders, Is it possible with Bitcoins?

Tags: transactions, client, payment

Is there a service out there, or is there any intention to integrate Standing Order type transactions into the client ? (Every 30 days transfer 0.2BTC to a specific address for example).

Comment: possible duplicate: [How could recurring payments be implemented?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/545/5406)

Answer (score 3):

One way to accomplish this today is to run Bitcoin with the -server switch. Then, create a cron job (Linux) or scheduled task (Windows) that calls bitcoind with the proper arguments. Something like...

```
bitcoind sendtoaddress <address> <amount> <comment>
```

The up side of this method is that you can run a lot of different commands this way. See the [wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list) for a full list of available RPC calls.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the client could be relied on for this as it would need to be running all the time.

So you would need a 3rd party e-wallet service.

Technically this would be very easy to do.